# Wordpress: why is my global variable not being set?

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables

I am running Wordpress 4.3.1. There are 2 plugins in question here: mine and some other author's.

I modified his code a bit to capture the permalink for a `$post_id` returned after using `wp_insert_post` into a global variable, like so:

```
// This is inside one public function of his...

$post_id = wp_insert_post($question_array);

        if($post_id){

            global $fd_success_post_id;
            $fd_success_post_id = get_permalink($post_id);

// The rest of his code does other stuff...not related...
```

I used the global variable `$fd_success_post_id` inside one of my PHP files, but when I check if it's set it says that it's not. Why might this be happening?

```
global $fd_success_post_id;

if(isset($fd_success_post_id)){
    echo $fd_success_post_id;
}
else{
    echo '$fd_success_post_id not set';
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `$fd_success_post_id` is not defined. To make it work define as global there also

```
global $fd_success_post_id;

if(isset($fd_success_post_id)){
    echo $fd_success_post_id;
}
else{
    echo '$fd_success_post_id not set';
}
```

Comment: It is already defined higher up (4 lines) in my file, so this isn't the issue. I will edit my question accordingly.